# Seekbar server: Origin Down

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-seekbar

I am developing an android app and I am using seekbar it was working in the morning and now it is showing me following error while running the app. It is showing that seekbar server is down and you need to enable Gradle offline mode.

```
Could not HEAD 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/warkiz/widget/indicatorseekbar/2.1.2/indicatorseekbar-2.1.2.pom'. Received status code 521 from server: Origin Down
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously synced this project, you can try enabling offline mode.

[image: Offline work enabled]

Comment: Though if you don't have a cached version of some dependency, then it won't work.